# Is the new Tokyo Fish Market in Toyosu open to visitors?

Tags: food-and-drink, sightseeing, tokyo

The famed [Tsukiji fish market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsukiji_fish_market) closed last weekend, with its replacement the [Toyosu fish market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyosu_Market) opening for business today.

**Is the new market open to tourists?**  I'm specifically interested in the tuna auctions, walking the market floor and whether there are any sushi restaurants open to the public.

Comment: No. It's only open to employees.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not yet open to the general public (which includes tourists I believe), but it will be starting 13 Oct 2018 (Sat) from 10:00 am to 5:00 pm. From 15 Oct 2018 (Mon) onwards, it will be open from 5:00 am to 5:00 pm, except for Sundays, holidays, and market days off.

Note: The **tuna auctions will not** be viewable to the public until 15 Jan 2019 (Tue). Details are not yet available, but will be posted later.

> I'm specifically interested in the tuna auctions, walking the market floor and whether there are any sushi restaurants open to the public.

There are sushi restaurants and you can view the tuna auction (from January next year). As for *actually* walking on the market floor, I was finally able to talk with the General Affairs Division (03-5320-5720) and the gentleman who answered said that **access into the actual market floor is not allowed**. (I think this is understandable as if it were allowed, then market operations would be obstructed by the public.)

What is allowed:

1. From 13 Oct 2018: Market operations can be viewed from the deck which is on the 2nd floor. The deck is separated by a glass panel and one can see the market workers below.
2. From 15 Jan 2019: Tuna auctions can also be viewed from the same deck.

References:

1. [Toyosu Market Visitor's Guide (English)](http://www.shijou.metro.tokyo.jp/toyosu/pdf/kenngaku/hajimaru-english.pdf)
2. [Toyosu Market Tour (Japanese)](http://www.shijou.metro.tokyo.jp/toyosu/kenngaku/)
3. [Toyosu Market Tour Details (Japanese)](http://www.shijou.metro.tokyo.jp/press/2018/1004_2.html)
4. Toyosu Market General Affairs Division (03-5320-5720)

Comment: Thanks, but while it sounds like you'll be able to *view* the trading floors from an observation deck, it's not actually possible to *visit* the floor?

Comment: @jpatokal Please see updated answer.